# Display product's name, its average quantity in all warehouses, and warehouse name that has the greatest quantity of each product

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to display a list of product names where the ID is between 100-105, with the average quantity in all warehouses, and the name of the warehouse that has the most product quantity (for each product). The only problem is that the average (`f_avg`) is not working, instead, `f_avg` is displaying the greatest quantity of the product.

The output example is:

1. Kingston HyperX Predator average product: 173 mostly found in San Francisco
2. Intel Xeon E5-2687W V4 average product: 90 mostly found in Toronto
3. EVGA 12G-P4-3992-KR average product: 178 mostly found in San Francisco

This is my code, anyone know what's wrong with the average. Thanks for your help

```
DECLARE
        CURSOR cur_detail IS
          SELECT p.product_name, round(avg(i.quantity)), w.warehouse_name
          FROM   products p
          join inventories i on p.product_id=i.product_id
          join warehouses w on i.warehouse_id=w.warehouse_id
          where (p.product_id between 100 and 105) and w.warehouse_name =(select w.warehouse_name from warehouses w where w.warehouse_id=i.warehouse_id and i.quantity=(select max(i.quantity) from inventories i where p.product_id=i.product_id))
            group by p.product_name,w.warehouse_name;
        TYPE type_record_type IS RECORD (
          f_name products.product_name%TYPE,
          f_avg inventories.quantity%type,
          f_wh warehouses.warehouse_name%type);
        f_rec_type type_record_type; 
    BEGIN
        OPEN cur_detail;
        LOOP
            FETCH cur_detail INTO f_rec_type;
            EXIT WHEN cur_detail%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.Put_line(f_rec_type.f_name||' average product: '||f_rec_type.f_avg||' mostly found in '||f_rec_type.f_wh);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur_detail;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are grouping by warehouse name as well, it is affecting your average.  If you find your average before looking up the warehouse with the highest quantity, then your average should be correct.

Something like this should give you what you need.

#### Example

```
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (SELECT product_name,
                     avg_quantity,
                     (SELECT w.warehouse_name
                        FROM warehouses w
                       WHERE warehouse_id = (SELECT warehouse_id
                                               FROM inventories i
                                              WHERE p.product_id = i.product_id
                                             HAVING i.quantity = MAX (i.quantity)))    AS warehouse_name
                FROM (  SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, AVG (i.quantity) AS avg_quantity
                          FROM products p JOIN inventories i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
                         WHERE (p.product_id BETWEEN 100 AND 105)
                      GROUP BY p.product_id, p.product_name))
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            x.product_name || ' average product: ' || x.avg_quantity || ' mostly found in ' || x.warehouse_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```